# In app promotion best practices

Tags: iphone

I'd like to create a framework to advertise my other apps in an app. I think I can simply create a UIButton placed in main menu screen or home view to lead users to an UIView which contains our other app's info. However, in that way, if I want to update or add new other apps in the UIView, I need to create a new version for the app.

I need an approach that I can update the other app list whenever I want.
Thanks for reading!

Comment: why don't you connect to a database where you store a simple table of your apps information?

Comment: As rad said, you should have a webserver, online database or whatever you want to retrieve the information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setup a webservice that will return a random one out of a list or the latest one etc + a url to an image online. that way the app will remain the same and its only the backend that needs to be updated

Comment: Thank Simon. I got your idea and researching the technical side now.

Comment: no problem, this is a good link on creating restful webservices with java. http://www.vogella.com/articles/REST/article.html

Comment: Currently, I'm using DreamHost to host. Can I setup RESTFul webservice on it?

Comment: sorry no, it says here: http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Java  that they don't support J2EE which is what is required to do the above in java. The only other method I'm familiar with is using c# with ASP.NET but again I don't believe they support IIS. This may need to be another question on stackoverflow im afraid

Comment: sorry just came to mind, I no http://www.godaddy.com/ let you choose whether you want an IIS server or not, I used them once before a long time ago, no complaints about it. but not sure if your familiar with IIS, ASP or C#